# htaccess rewrite assets directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to rewrite assets directory from mysite.com/demo/assets/ to mysite.com/assets using htaccess.

i tried lots of combination but none of them works, i think it has something to do with my current htaccess parameters

Original code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

I did the trick via bellow code, but js functions which are adding css parameters doesn't work any more.

```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/demo/assets/(.*)$ /assets/$1
```

I have created actual /demo/assets folder and added htaccess files with bellow parameter, it also does the trick for css but js is still not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demo/assets/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /assets/$1 [L,NC]
```

anybody help

Ok finally after full night research i found the source of issue. js is glitching because of tinymce library, when i upload it manually in demo/assets/plugins all seems to work fine!
now i am trying to find out why tinymce is glitching and keep it in shared /assets folder.

### hope i can receive advice's.

strangely issue seems to be in demo/assets/plugins/tinymce/langs dir which contains only readme.md

Comment: You want to remove `demo` from your URL?

Comment: Yes but only for /assets/

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please refer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677047/htaccess-rewrite-assets-directory/54677437#54677437

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect /demo/assets /assets
```

Answer (score 0):

***Using .htaccess***

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demo/assets/$ /assets/ [L,R=301]
```

OR

RedirectMatch uses a regular expression that is matched against the URL path.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/demo/assets/$ /assets/
```

***Using routes.php file***  (in application/config/routes.php)

Try this :

```
$route['assets'] = "demo/assets/$1";
```

Then you have to change every link in your coding from `<?php echo site_url();?>demo/assets/` to `<?php echo site_url();?>assets/`

**Note :-** This will be good solution for custom URLs in Codeigniter.
**NO NEED TO CHANGE .htaccess.**

Please refer the CI documentation regarding URI routing for more information.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: yes, i have multi directory setup where demo folder just contains index.php and config/custom-config.php files. i want to do redirect via htaccess because assets is called via base_url('assets/'); in multiple files and  because of frequent devoper updates i do not feel comfortable modifying core script files. p.s. tried your htaccess it doesn't work

Comment: @BackOffice `routes.php` is a config file, not a core file!

Comment: I think, It's better to change `routes.php` file for this particular single redirect.

Comment: In core i was referring to  base_url('assets/'); , will routs bypass base_url parameter ? reference to htaccess i tried new methods but page is still loading without css

Comment: @BackOffice. Yes. It will bypass base_url parameter. All routes ONLY from `/demo/assets/` will be redirected to `/assets/`. At least try it that way.

Comment: After changing to this, `$route['assets'] = "demo/assets/$1";`  you have to change every link in your coding from `<?php echo site_url();?>demo/assets/` to `<?php echo site_url();?>assets/`

Comment: well as mentioned above there is no site_url();?>demo/assets/ it is executed from  base_url('assets/'); and i do not want to touch view folder.